# Can I get or set coordinates, width or height of an element positioned statically in pure JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can I get or set coordinates, width and height of an element positioned statically in pure JS?
If yes - how?
in jQuery?

Comment: have you tried searching about your question?

Answer (score 2):

If jQuery is acceptable you can use .position() method to retrieve #your_element top and left position offset its parent.

```
$('#your_element').position().left
$('#your_element').position().top
```

and size using :

```
$('#your_element').width()
$('#your_element').height()
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. This should help to get you started.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function whereAmI(e){
                //Note that css styles may not be accurate, as one can see with top/left here.
                //It is just to show possibilities.

                alert(
                    'Width (css): ' + (e.style.width || '') + '\n' +
                    'Height (css): ' + (e.style.height || '') + '\n' +
                    'Left (css): ' + (e.style.left || '') + '\n' +
                    'Top (css): ' + (e.style.top || '') + '\n\n' +
                    'Width (offset): ' + e.offsetWidth.toString() + 'px\n' +
                    'Height (offset): ' + e.offsetHeight.toString() + 'px\n' +
                    'Left (offset): ' + e.offsetLeft.toString() + 'px\n' +
                    'Top (offset): ' + e.offsetTop.toString() + 'px'
                );      
            }

            function setTo5050(){
                var tE = document.getElementById('adiv');
                if (tE){
                    tE.style.height = '50px';
                    tE.style.width = '50px';
                    tE.style.left = '50%';
                    tE.style.top = '50%';
                };
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id = 'adiv' style = 'background: lime' onclick = 'whereAmI(this)'>Where am I?</div>
        <b onclick = 'setTo5050()'>Set to 50px 50px</b>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks , Lain. I am getting sick of CSS. Almost totally mad. Who invented this crap?  Everything can be made relatively of size of font!?  An element positioning called 'static' which is actually 'automatic' - set by engine. Relative position is not relative to any other object but itself, so I guess the right name for it would be 'shifted', not 'relative'. 'Absolute' is not absolute, but 'Coordinated' and so on so on...

Comment: Do you still need any further help on this?

Answer (score 1):

Function extends the set and get widht height for particular element

Run below code snippet you will find the style from js appplied can accessible by script.

```js
const setDivWidHeig = document.getElementById('setDivWidHeig');
const divElm = document.getElementById('divElm');
divElm.style.width = '90px';
divElm.style.height = '90px';

setDivWidHeig.addEventListener("click", setDivWidHeigClick);

function setDivWidHeigClick() {
    divElm.style.width = parseInt(divElm.style.width) + 10 + 'px';
    divElm.style.height = parseInt(divElm.style.height) + 10 + 'px';
    divElm.innerHTML = 'width=>' + divElm.style.width + '<br>height=>' + divElm.style.height;
}
setDivWidHeigClick();
```

```css
div {
    display: block;
    background: #ccc;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="divElm"></div>
<button id="setDivWidHeig">Add height/width</button>
```